# Launch screen is black when set to a storyboard file

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, iboutlet, launch-screen

I am [using a storyboard to get the correct height of a navigation bar in my launch image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26481129/35690).

However, after customizing the view controller a bit, it now displays a black screen instead of a launch image.

When I set it to a brand new view controller, everything is fine. It seems like the original view controller is now in a bad state.

How can I fix this?

(I'm running iOS 8.2 simulator on Xcode 6.2.)

Answer (score 12):

The problem in this case was that there was an **outlet set on the view controller**.

If there are any outlets on the initial view controller (or, if the initial view controller is a navigation controller, the root view controller), the system will not render any launch image, and instead show a black screen.

In my case I have my target's **Main Interface** set to the same value as the **Launch Screen File** (both set to storyboards). Once it launches the real app, I want to manipulate the view a bit (hence why I had an IBOutlet). After deleting the IBOutlets, I was able to manipulate the view by using `-[UIView viewWithTag:]`.

**Note:** When the view controller is being used to render an image for the launch screen, none of the code in the class is called (e.g. `-[UIViewController viewDidLoad]` is never called). On the other hand, when the view controller is being used for the **Main Interface**, the code is executed normally, as you would expect.

Comment: This helped me, Thanks :) For some animation logic they connected the image to the ViewController. After removing that connection it works :)

Answer (score 2):

For me the fix was to check "is initial view controller". Before that I got only a black screen, now finally I get the View Controller as the Splash

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If everything is fine but still Blank black screen appears ... it may be caused by a static size `.png` image ... either use multiple sizes`.png` or go for `.svg` or `.png` single image ...
also In iOS 14 and later, the launch screen is limited to 25 MB according to Human Interface Guidelines by apple.